# Filling in missing column details in SQL table when similar rows are populated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a (probably) very easy question for a SQL server data issue. I have some test data with missing Customer IDs in certain rows - but I know that when the Details column is the same, I will have the same ID.

Meaning, for row 6 Customer will be 3 since it has the same Details as row 5 and 4.

| Customer | Details | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40495BS | 15/01/2022 | 300 |
| 1 | 40495BS | 10/02/2022 | 250 |
| 2 | 83825NO | 31/10/2021 | 100 |
| 3 | 90401HI | 01/06/2022 | 525 |
| 3 | 90401HI | 07/09/2022 | 130 |
|  | 90401HI | 09/05/2022 | -130 |
| 4 | 17452RE | 14/07/2022 | 125 |

Any ideas for a fix to return all the missing Customer IDs based on this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `MAX()` used as an analytic function might work well here:

```sql
SELECT MAX(Customer) OVER (PARTITION BY Details) AS Customer,
       Details, Date, Amount
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly on the larger sample too! :) Simple and efficient solution!